# Node js post request with axios and validate the user with joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, postman, joi

How can I validate the request and send that data?
I am working with node js and Joi on a validation package for node. I'm trying to make a post request with node.js and when I try to run it, I get the error like this in postman
`{TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)}.then is not a function}.`
How can I fix this?

```js
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  axios.post("https://m2.leanscale.com/index.php/rest/default/V1/customers", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${AccessToken} `,
    }.then((response, request) => {
      const data = request.body;
      const schema = Joi.object({
        firstname: Joi.string().min(5).max(50).required(),
        lastname: Joi.string().min(5).max(50).required(),
        email: Joi.string().email().required(),
        password: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required(),
      });
      schema
        .validate(data, schema, (err, value) => {
          // const id = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9999999);
          if (err) {
            res.status(422).json({
              status: "error",
              message: "Invalid request data",
              data: data,
            });
          } else {
            res.json({
              status: "success",
              message: "User created successfully",
              data: Object.assign(value),
            });
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          res.send(error);
        });
    }),
  });
});
```

Comment: no one can help me ?

Comment: Not sure if this the only error, but there's a missing `})` right before the `.then` and you can remove this `}),` from the bottom...